# Inheriting Custom Operators in Python?

Tags: inheritance, python-3.x

If I have class A that defines `__cmp__`, and class B that extends class A, it seems like I have to redefine `__cmp__` in class B.  Is this correct?

Is there a better workaround than implementing a method "cmp" in class A and calling it from the separate implementations of `__cmp__` in class A and class B?

Thanks,
-aj

---

UPDATE:  The issue seems to be my lack of Python 3 exposure.  As I read it, `__cmp__` should no longer be used:  http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons

Instead, I've re-implemented my classes using the new ordering comparison operators:  [http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/reference/datamodel.html#object.**lt**](http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)

Comment: why do you think you need to redefine it in B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a class called "A", and that class has a definition for __ cmp __.

And let's assume you extend class A:

```
class B(A):
```

So to retrieve __ cmp __ from class A from within class B one would use:

`A.__cmp__` from within class B

Is my guess.